# How to remove scroll bar form prettyPhoto lightbox?

Tags: php, jquery, css, plugins, prettyphoto

I have used one plugin for lightbox .i.e `prittyPhoto`,

Everything is fine in each browser except in `ie7`.

There will display scrollbar over lightbox. So how can i remove scrollbar in IE7 browser?/

Comment: does this concerns php ?

Comment: no, no concerns  with php

Comment: only problem is scrolling..

Comment: You tagged your question as PHP.

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below ones

```
body{overflow-x: hidden;}
```

In which case if you apply it to html rather than body

```
html{overflow-x: hidden;}
```

else

```
html{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Try putting if you want separate style sheet from others

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    Link to alternate style sheet
    OR
    <style> /*CSS in here*/ </style>
<![endif]-->
```